# Tengo un par de dudas sobre desarrollar apps para Android

Tags: android

Empecé hace poco en la programación, pero me interesa mucho el desarrollo de apps para smartphones y quiero comenzar por android, pero tengo algunas dudas.

He visto que lo recomendable es programar en Java pero que también es posible hacerlo en C++, hasta ahora me siento mucho más cómodo usando C++´, será un inconveniente si lo uso para programar en Android?

Como le desarrollo una interfaz de usuario a mi aplicacion de Android? Que tan complejo es esto último?

Comment: Claro que puedes usar C++, mediante el NDK, te recomiendo leer: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts.html?hl=es-419 Para crear la UI se usan los layouts, https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/templates.html , se pueden crear programaticamente pero en el caso del NDK es más complejo.

Answer (score 1):

Échale un ojo al ndk para android para poder programar en c++ en android, https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html

Si quieres ir con c++ deberías buscar información sobre ndk en lugar de sdk

Cabe decir que tanto como en java con en c++ no es propiamente java ni c++ puro, por lo cual una aplicación nativa en c++ tendría que adaptarse para android